# CSS: Absolute Positioning, where are the (absolute) coordinates of an image actually located in the image?

Tags: html, css

pretty much the title.

backstory: I am designing a game engine in javascript based on absolute positioning and I really need to know if the absolute positioning coordinate itself is in the center of the image(which would be awsome!), or else in one of the corners, but if so, which corner?

I think it's the top left corner, but I'm not sure.

I really need to know so I can work out collisions between images, and actually give the objects in the game boundaries other than rectangles. I am tinkering around now, but it would save me a lot of time and I would feel more secure if someone could just let me know for sure.

I have an image in a div, and I am setting all css properties in the style property of the div, including bottom, left, height, and width

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set the `top` and `left`... that's how much space to give at the *top* and *left* of the element you're positioning absolutely. Now if you don't give it a width and height, you can use `bottom` and `right` to make it so it takes up all the space except for whatever you specify in those style attributes.

A simple [demo](http://jsbin.com/opogep/1) should be enough to illustrate this...

I should mention that absolute means absolute to the origin of the body (top left corner of page). The exception to this is when the parent element of your absolutely positioned element is `position: relative` See this [demo](http://jsbin.com/opogep/2)

Comment: Check this out: http://jsbin.com/opogep/6.  It shows the (absolute) coordinates depends on the height when i set the thing using bottom.  So i guess the absolute coordinate is always in the top left of the containing element when i position with bottom, and always in the top left no matter what when i position with top.

Comment: No, when you use bottom, it'll be that many px from the bottom of the element. Those attributes are just saying "`X`px from `direction`". Both logo2 and point2 are at the same top-left because they have the same top and left position. Both logo and point are at the same bottom and left since they have the same bottom and left position. Now because logo is taller than point, it is "up" more, but the bottom left position is still the same, as defined in the style.

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, `left` means how far between the element and the left side of the parent element, e.g. `<body>`, or an element with `position: relative`.

Same goes for the others, e.g. `bottom` means how far up from the bottom edge.

However, I have made an example that allows positioning from the center: http://jsfiddle.net/tbRfm/1/.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner">
        Inner stuff here, or set a <code>background-image</code>.
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    left: 200px;
    top: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    right: 50px;
    bottom: 50px;
    background: #eee;
    text-align: center
}
```

This works in all IE versions (at least the ones I could test at [IE NetRenderer](http://netrenderer.com): IE5.5 - IE10).

Easy test: if you make the `left` and `top` values of `.wrapper` `0`, the box will be half cut-off: http://jsfiddle.net/tbRfm/3/.